# UIButton not working on animated subView

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I want to add two buttons to a subview that appears over the parent view when the view will appear. The buttons are initialized correctly and appear but they don´t react when pressed. Does anybody know why? Here is my code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //Animation View
    imageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 499, 320, 0)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"];
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottom];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.5f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^(void) {
                         imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 92, 320, 320);

                     }
                     completion:NULL];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
    // Animation View Buttons
    //1 Amazon
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *button=[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    [button1 setImage:button forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 290, 80, 30);
    button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    button1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(openAmazon:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageView addSubview:button1];

    //2 iTunes
    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button2 setImage:button forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(82, 290, 80, 30);
    button2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    button2.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    [button2 addTarget:self
     action:@selector(openiTunes:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [imageView addSubview:button2];



}
```

Comment: where is your openAmazon and openiTunes functions? have u written them?

Comment: Why are you adding UIButton inside UIImageView?

Comment: @lakesh: Yes, I wrote them. They are in the same viewController; Paramasivan: because I only want the buttons to appear when the animated ImageView appears. The solution to my problem is given by nmock, I had to enable the user interaction of my imageview :) But thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the `userInteractionEnabled` property on the imageView:

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: that was the solution to the problem! thanx!

Answer (score 5):

you need to use the option UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction

```
...
options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
```

you are bringing your image view to the front after increasing its frame, this is blocking the  buttons actions